# Generated sigma algebras and independence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I have the following question regarding independence of generated $\sigma$-algebras:

Let $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ an i.i.d sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1$, define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ I am trying to prove that $E(X_1|\mathcal{G}
_n)=E(X_1|S_n)$ where $\mathcal{G}_n:=\sigma(\cup_{k=n}^\infty S_k)$

For that purpose, I am wondering if it is true that $\sigma(S_n)$ and $\sigma(\cup \sigma(X_1), \sigma(S_n))$ are independent of $\sigma(\cup_{i=n+1}^\infty S_{i})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: this would imply that $S_n$ is independent of $S_{n+1}$. If you assume integrability, this implies that $$\mathbb E\left[S_{n+1}\right]=\mathbb E\left[S_{n+1}\mid S_n\right]=S_n+\mathbb E\left[X_{n+1}\mid S_n\right]=S_n+\mathbb E\left[X_{n+1}\right]$$
hence $S_n$ is constant.

Comment: You are right, now I see that the proof has to be made by taking $\sigma(S_{n+1})$ as $\sigma(\cup S_n X_{n+1})$ and using the independence...